# Does python provide a list of special characters for uuencoding?

Tags: python, uuencode

I can find the uuencode character mappings on wikipedia. Does python have a means to loop through this list?

```
for x in [builtin_uuencode_mappings]:
    print(x)
```

I would like to focus on special characters such as "!@#$" and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to verify that Python uses the same characters that are listed in Wikipedia?

Comment: I am wanting to be lazy. I wonder if a magic list of characters exists somewhere in the python code that I could loop around.  I could type in this "!@#$%^&*()_+-+~`" (I just did) but wondering if this list is already part of python.

Comment: Python can already encode and decode uuencoding. With that one *could* generate the character mappings like this: `[chr(binascii.b2a_uu(bytes([4*i]))[1]) for i in range(64)]` for python3 or `[binascii.b2a_uu(chr(4*i))[1] for i in range(64)]` in python2.

Comment: @Wombatz - tks - that's good enought for me; I'll mark as answer if you respond as an answer vs comment.

Comment: I will need some time to think about why this actually works...

Comment: @Wombatz it works because you shift each value left by 2 bits (the `4*` part) then encode it to a single character. Totally brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python already has built-in support for encoding and decoding uuencoded messages.

```
from codecs import encode  # decode also works
print(encode("my message", 'uu'))
# -> 'begin 666 <data>\n*;7D@;65S<V%G90  \n \nend\n'
```

Internally python uses the `binascii` package to encode or decode the message line by line. We can use that to encode a single byte or even all bytes in the `range(64)` (because uuencoding tranforms 6bit into an ascii character: `2**6 == 64`).

To generate all necessary bit patterns we can count to 64 and shift the result by 2 bit to the left. That way the highest 6 bits count from 0 to 64. Then it's just a matter of converting that into python `bytes`, uuencode them and extract the actual character.

In python2

```
from binascii import b2a_uu
for byte in range(64):
    pattern = chr(byte << 2)  # str and bytes are identical in python2
    encoded = b2a_uu(pattern)
    character = encoded[1]  # encoded[0] is the character count in that line
    print "{:2} -> {!r}".format(byte, character)
```

In python3 the first part is a little bit ugly.

```
from binascii import b2a_uu
for byte in range(64):
    pattern = bytes([byte << 2])  # chr().encode() will not work!
    encoded = b2a_uu(pattern)
    character = chr(encoded[1]) 
    print(f"{byte:2} -> {character!r}")
```

Thanks to Mark Ransom who explained why the bit shifting actually works.